# Advanced Timestamp Calculations (Even and Odd Rows Totalling)

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

I am creating a personal time card system as a pet project and I have everything down pat except the totaling of times for each day and for the week. Let's say I have 4 punches for the day pulled from my database using a while loop:

```
[1] 2013-03-01 07:00:00 - IN - (FOR DAY)
[2] 2013-03-01 12:00:00 - OUT (TO LUNCH)
[3] 2013-03-01 12:30:00 - IN (FROM LUNCH)
[4] 2013-03-01 15:30:00 - OUT (FOR DAY)
```

My question is how would I go about creating a running total to spit out a total of 8 hours? I have thought about this for days with no logical solution in my mind. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want it to spit out as many of those rows as it takes to equal 8 hours? This is kinda confusing, what are the numbers at the end representing?

Comment: I've edited the timestamps for clarity. These are time card punches that represent that I (for example) have forked for today. I clocked in at 7:00am, out at 12:00pm, in at 12:30pm and out at 3:30pm totaling 8 hours worked. How can I use PHP to total these hours automatically? Thanks!

Comment: They're stored just like that? That might be kinda hard to manipulate, I'd suggest maybe using sql to store them in columns "date" and "time." But the easiest way to do it would be to do this: (4-1)-(3-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *probably* change the structure of your table. The underlying idea is the notion of a working period, which requires a start time and an end time. The current structure splits that fact into two rows. Use one row instead.

```
work_periods
time_in              time_out
--
2013-03-01 07:00:00  2013-03-01 12:00:00
2013-03-01 12:30:00  2013-03-01 15:30:00
```

If you have a table like this, you can easily get the difference in minutes with timestampdiff().

```
select time_in, time_out, 
    timestampdiff(minute, time_in, time_out) elapsed_time
from work_periods;
```

You can return the same data from your existing table. I think you should only do this as a temporary approach. This kind of structure makes it hard to identify "in"s that are missing an "out", and "out"s that are missing an "in".

```
create table work_periods (
  work_ts datetime not null,
  in_or_out varchar(5) not null,
  primary key (work_ts)
  );

insert into work_periods values
('2013-03-01 07:00:00', 'IN'),
('2013-03-01 12:00:00', 'OUT'),
('2013-03-01 12:30:00', 'IN'),
('2013-03-01 15:30:00', 'OUT');
```

The "out" that goes with each "in" is the earliest "out" that's later than the "in".

```
select wp1.work_ts time_in,
       (select min(wp2.work_ts) 
        from work_periods wp2
        where wp2.work_ts > wp1.work_ts
          and wp2.in_or_out = 'OUT') time_out
from work_periods wp1
where wp1.in_or_out = 'IN';
```

If I had the choice, I'd

- build an updateable view from that last SELECT statement,
- update application code to use the view, and finally
- replace the view with the base table at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: This is very useful for me in the future, thank you! The issue I am having is that the entire script is already programed for the structure I have. Is there a way to retrieve two results at once with a SELECT query, or subtract the differences using a unix time stamp? Thanks again!

Comment: Updated answer. Ignored Unix timestamps, because I hate storing Unix timestamps in a database with a passion that burns like the sun.